# I need to konw if Aurora MySql supports transactions when called from a Lambda function written in Node.js

Tags: mysql, lambda, amazon-aurora

I am looking for information about AWS Aurora Serverless MySql.  I will be calling from a Node.js Lambda function. I need to know if this software stack supports transactions with Commit and Rollback. I can't seem to find documentation about this.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/amazon-aurora-mysql-db-admin-handbook/transaction-management-and-autocommit.html

Comment: You could just _try it._ Connect with a MySQL client, create a test table, begin a transaction, insert a row, then rollback. Then query the table and see that your row is not there.

Comment: I don't think I can use the MySql commands directly, I use the AWS RDS service to communicate with Aurora.